# MapboxGL access token with URL restriction returning 403 Forbidden

Tags: mapbox, access-token, mapbox-gl-js

We use mapboxGL JS v1.8 for a simple single page store locator that loads a mapbox map and markers for various locations. Until yesterday 12/20 , I used an access token created over on the mapbox account with URL restriction to limit access to just our domain. This was working  just fine until yesterday when  it suddenly started returning a 403 forbidden error. The only way to "fix" it has been to remove the URL restrictions on the access token after which it works fine.
There have been  no changes to the app or the domain or to the access tokens for many months but for some reason  the URL restriction on the access token prevents access to even  the restricted domain. I've inspected the request headers sent to mapbox for the "origin" and "Referrer" headers and they are the same domain as they were previously when they were working fine.
Just curious if anyone else has experienced this issue and how it was resolved. I've sent a support ticket to mapbox but we're not a premium customer so , not sure if there will be any response.
(We've not exceeded any mapbox usage limits and our account is not overdue or anything like that)

The following mapbox-gl libraries are used in the app:
https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.1/mapbox-gl.js
https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.2.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js
https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.2.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css
https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.1/mapbox-gl.css

The code snippet used to load the map is :

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = config.accessToken; // accesstoken created on the account
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'mapContainer',
        style: config.mapStyle,
        center: validCoordinates,
        zoom: 5
    });
```